# Simple serial point-to-point communication protocol

Tags: embedded, serial-port, protocols

I need a simple communication protocol between two devices (a PC and a microcontroller). The PC must send some commands and parameters to the micro. The micro must transmit an array of bytes (data from sensor).

The data must be [noise protected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_detection_and_correction) (besides parity checking, I think I need some other data correction method).

Is there any standard solution to do this? (I need only an idea, not the complete solution).

P.S. Any advice is appreciated. *P.P.S Sorry for any grammar mistakes, I hope you understand.*

**Edit 1.** I have not decided whether it will be ***master/slave*** protocol or both sides can initiate communication. The PC must know when micro have done a job and can send data. It can continuously poll the micro if data is ready, or the micro can send data, when a job is done. I don't know which is better and simpler.

**Edit 2.** ***Hardware and [physical layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Layer) protocol.*** Since [RS-232](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232)C serial standard used in the PC, I will use [asynchronous communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_serial_communication). I will use only RxD, TxD and GND signals. I can't use additional wires because the microcontroller AFAIK doesn't support them. BTW I'm using the [AVR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmel_AVR) ATmega128 chip.

So I will use fixed baud rate, 8 bits of data, 2 stop bits without parity checking (or with?).

***[Data link protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Link_Layer)***. That's what my question primarily concerned about. Thanks for suggesting [HDLC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Level_Data_Link_Control), [PPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol) and [Modbus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modbus) protocols. I will research on it.

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815029/

Comment: "The data must be noise protected". Then you shouldn't be using RS-232 to begin with... that's an amateur solution. Use RS-422/RS-485.

Comment: @Vanuan did you have a look at my answer below ? I believe it provides a nice and friendly solution

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I would use [HDLC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDLC).  I have had good luck with it in the past.  I would for a point to point serial just use the [Asynchronous framing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Level_Data_Link_Control#Asynchronous_framing) and forget about all of the other control stuff as it would probably be overkill.

In addition to using HDLC for the framing of the packet. I format my packet like the following. This is how options are passed using 802.11

```
U8 cmd;
U8 len;
u8 payload[len];
```

The total size of each command packet is len +2

You then define commands like

```
#define TRIGGER_SENSOR 0x01
#define SENSOR_RESPONSE 0x02
```

The other advantage is that you can add new commands and if you design your parser correctly to ignore undefined commands then you will have some backwards compatibility.

So putting it all together the packet would look like the following.

```
 // total packet length minus flags len+4
 U8 sflag;   //0x7e start of packet end of packet flag from HDLC
 U8 cmd;     //tells the other side what to do.
 U8 len;     // payload length
 U8 payload[len];  // could be zero len
 U16 crc;
 U8 eflag;   //end of frame flag
```

The system will then monitor the serial stream for the flag 0x7e and when it is there you check the length to see if it is pklen >= 4 and pklen=len+4 and that the crc is valid. Note  do not rely on just crc for small packets you will get a lot of false positives also check length. If the length or crc does not match just reset the length and crc and start with decoding the new frame. If it is a match then copy the packet to a new buffer and pass it to your command processing function. Always reset length and crc when a flag is received.

For your command processing function grab the cmd and len and then use a switch to handle each type of command. I also require that a certain events send a response so the system behaves like a remote procedure call that is event driven.

So for example the sensor device can have a timer or respond to a command to take a reading.  It then would format a packet and send it to the PC and the PC would respond that it received the packet. If not then the sensor device could resend on a timeout.

Also when you are doing a network transfer you should design it as a network stack like the [OSI modle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) as [Foredecker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18256/foredecker) points don't forget about the [physical layer stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815758/simple-serial-point-to-point-communication-protocol/817750#817750).  My post with the HDLC is the [data link layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Layer_2:_Data_Link_Layer) and the [RPC and command handling is the Application Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Layer_7:_Application_Layer).

Comment: +1 for asynchronous framing. It solved my question asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815029/a-way-to-convert-byte-stream-to-packet-stream-in-c89-on-an-embedded-device

Comment: Rex, Why do you put eflag at the end of the frames? Sflag with sflag escaping + length should be sufficient to read the frames.

Comment: Because if he only uses sflag, he has to wait for the next frame. By using eflag, he knows (when he gets eflag) that he's got the whole frame.

Comment: As Micheal points out it is very important and acts as the trigger for accepting or throwing away the packet you do not want to rely on possible corrupt data to determine the end of a packet.

Answer (score 12):

I read this question a few months back, having exactly the same issue, and didn't really find anything efficient enough for a tiny 8-bit micro with tiny amounts of RAM. So inspired by CAN and LIN I built something to do the job. I called it MIN (Microcontroller Interconnect Network) and I've uploaded it to GitHub here:

https://github.com/min-protocol/min

There are two implementations there: one in embedded C, one in Python for a PC. Plus a little "hello world" test program where the PC sends commands and the firmware lights an LED. I blogged about getting this up and running on an Arduino board here:

https://kentindell.wordpress.com/2015/02/18/micrcontroller-interconnect-network-min-version-1-0/

MIN is pretty simple. I fixed the layer 0 representation (8 data bits, 1 stop bit, no parity) but left the baud rate open. Each frame starts with three 0xAA bytes which in binary is 1010101010, a nice pulsetrain to do autobaud rate detection if one end wants to dynamically adapt to the other. Frames are 0-15 bytes of payload, with a 16-bit Fletcher's checksum as well as a control byte and an 8-bit identifier (to tell the application what the payload data contains).

The protocol uses character stuffing so that 0xAA 0xAA 0xAA always indicates start-of-frame. This means that if a device comes out of reset it always syncs with the start of the next frame (a design goal for MIN was never to pass up an incomplete or incorrect frame). This also means there's no need to have specific inter-byte and inter-frame timing constraints. Full details of the protocol are in the GitHub repo wiki.

There's room for future improvements with MIN. I've left some hooks in there for block message passing (4 bits of the control byte are reserved) and for higher-level negotiation of capabilities (identifier 0xFF is reserved) so there's plenty of scope for adding support for commonly required functionality.

Answer (score 11):

RS232 protocols are tricky.   The suggestion to use HDLC, is a good one, but its not the entire solution.   There are other things you need to decide:

- How will the baud rate between the two devices be determined?  Autobuad? Predefined, or set explicate?
- Will you do flow control in software or hardware or both?  Note, if you use hardware flow control then you *must* make sure, that the cables are built correctly.
- Speaking of cables, this is a huge pain with RS233.   Depending on the device, you may need to use a straight through cable, or a cross over cable, or a variant.
- Using a software based flow control mechanism can be effective as it allows the most simple cable to be used - just three wired (TX, RX, and common).
- Do you pick a 7 or 8 bit word?
- HW parity or software error checking.

I suggest you go with 8 data bits, no hardware parity, 1 stop bit, and use software based flow control.  You should use autobaud if your hardware supports it.  If not, then autobaud is devilishly difficult to do in software.

Comment: (1) I will use fixed baud rate. (2) I'm not sure if I need flow control. Traffic load isn't very high. (3) I have no any problems with cables, I can make them myself. (4) I will use three wired cable (TxD, Rxd and GND). (5) I pick a 8 bit word. (6) I need software error checking because HW parity detects only 50% of errors. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

There are some good answers in here, here are some useful pointers:

Even if your packets are not time-separated, the sync byte is an essential way of reducing the number of places you need to attempt to construct a packet from. Your devices will often have to deal with a bunch of junk data (i.e the end of a packet in flight when they turned on, or result of a hardware collision). Without a sync byte you will have to try to make a packet out of every byte you receive. The sync byte means that only 1/255 bytes of random noise could be the first byte of your packet. Also FANTASTIC when you want to snoop on your protocol.

Having an address on your packets or even just a bit saying master / slave or pc / device is useful when you look at the packets via a [snoop tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023181/good-free-rs232-serial-snoop-tool-for-protocol-development-debugging) of some type or another. You might do this by having a different sync byte for the PC than the DEVICE. Also, this will mean a device will not respond to its own echo.

You might want to look into error correction (such as [Hamming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code)). You package 8 bit of data into a 12 bit protected byte. Any one of those 12 bits can be flipped en-route and the original 8 bits retrieved. Useful for data storage (used on CDs) or where the device can't re-send easily (satellite links, one-way rf).

Packet numbers make life easier. A packet sent carries a number, responses carry the same number an a flag saying "response". This means that packets that never arrived (sync corrupted say) are easily detected by the sender and in full-duplex mode with a slow link, two commands can be sent before the first response is received. This also makes protocol analysis easier (A third party can understand which packets were received with no knowledge of the underlying protocol)

Having a single master is an awesome simplification. That said, in a full-duplex environment it does not matter much at all. Suffice to say you should always do it unless you are trying to save power or you are doing something event driven at the device end (input state changed, sample ready).

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion is modbus. 
It's an efficient and easy standard protocol for communication with devices that has sensors and parameters (for example a PLC). 
You can get the specifications at http://www.modbus.org. It’s been around since 1979 and is gaining in popularity, you will have no problem finding examples and libraries.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have enough experience to fully implement it. I use assembly and can't find any libraries. It's a heavy protocol. Nevertheless, I will keep it in mind. Thanks.

Comment: It's a lot of documentation to read through, but it actually isn't a lot of code when you implement it. The effort is probably on pair with the suggested HDLC.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternative protocol:

```
u8  Sync          // A constant value which always marks the start of a packet
u16 Length        // Number of bytes in payload
u8  Data[Length]  // The payload
u16 Crc           // CRC
```

Use RS232/UART, as the PC (serial port) and the processor (UART) can already handle that with minimum fuss (just need a [MAX232](http://www.maxim-ic.com/quick_view2.cfm/qv_pk/1798) chip or similar to do the level shifting).

And using RS232/UART, you don't have to worry about master/slave if it's not relevant. Flow control is available if necessary.

Suggested PC software: either write your own, or [Docklight](http://www.fuh-edv.de/docklight/) for simple monitoring and control (evaluation version is free).

For greater error checking, simplest is parity checking, or if you need something more powerful, maybe [convolutional coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_code).

In any case, whatever you do: **keep it simple!**

**EDIT:** Using RS232 with a PC is even easier than it used to be, as you can now get USB to RS232/TTL converters. One end goes into your PC's USB socket, and appears as a normal serial port; the other comes out to 5 V or 3.3 V signals that can be connected *directly* to your processor, with no level-shifting required.

We've used [TTL-232R-3V3](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/EvaluationKits/TTL-232R-3V3.htm) from FDTI Chip, which works perfectly for this kind of application.

Comment: That isn't a protocol - its simply a data structure.  You don't describe how flow control works, or buffering, or error detection or correction.

Comment: The low-level part, and the flow control, is handled by the hardware. The qeustion didn't mention buffering, so neither did I (hint: on the microcontroller, use circular buffers). I've given a couple of ideas for error detection & correction - but the rest is up to the questioner. I wouldn't want to make it too easy!

Comment: I think I need to guarantee that Sync number will not occur in Length, Data and CRC. Do I? Also I need to control that data is delivered (by transmitting some response to data). So I have to worry about master/slave. By flow control you mean hardware flow control? I think I will not use it. I will write PC software myself. I've chosen Linux operating system for the PC, so Docklight is not relevant. If I will use CRC, why I have to use parity checking? I haven't heard about convolutional coding, so I will check it out.

Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @Vanuan: (1) If you specify a minimum time between messages, than it's OK for the sync byte to also appear in the message, as its purpose is to signal the start of a message after that gap; this way it helps avoid errors due to noise between packets. (2) I did mean H/W flow control, but if the recipient acknowledges each packet, and can buffer the data fast enough, then it's not needed. (3) If you're using CRC, parity is not required, yes.

Comment: Please no more hand-designed, non standard protocols.

Comment: @Tim: if this is a custom application, a simple, custom, protocol _may_ be the best solution. A standard protocol is not necessarily the answer in all situations.

Comment: For the record, this _is_ a pretty "standard" protocol, as it contains the minimum items needed and custom RS-232 protocols have looked like this for the past 30 years or so. HDLC is completely overkill for a simple point-to-point connection where neither node is an external one.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding parity checks (as it's come up a few times here):

They're mostly useless. If you're concerned that a single bit may be changed in error, then it's highly likely that a second bit may also change and you'll get a false positive from the parity check.

Use something lightweight like CRC16 with a lookup table - it can be calculated as each byte is received and is basically just an XOR. Steve Melnikoff's suggestion is great for small micros.

I would also suggest transmitting human readable data, rather than raw binary (if performance is not your first priority). It will make debugging and log files much more pleasant.

Answer (score 4):

You can have a look at [`Telemetry`](https://github.com/Overdrivr/Telemetry) and its associated desktop implementation in python [`Pytelemetry`](https://github.com/Overdrivr/pytelemetry)

### Main features

It is a *PubSub-based protocol*, but unlike MQTT it is a point-to-point protocol, **no broker**.

As any pubsub protocol, you can **publish** from one end on a `topic` and be notified on the other end on that topic.

On the embedded side, publishing to a topic is as simple as :

```
publish("someTopic","someMessage")
```

For numbers:

```
publish_f32("foo",1.23e-4)
publish_u32("bar",56789)
```

This way of sending variables may seem limited, but the next milestone intends to add extra meaning to the topic's parsing by doing things like this :

```
// Add an indexing meaning to the topic
publish("foo:1",45) // foo with index = 1
publish("foo:2",56) // foo with index = 2

// Add a grouping meaning to the topic
publish("bar/foo",67) // foo is under group 'bar'

// Combine
publish("bar/foo:45",54)
```

This is good if you need to send arrays, complex data structures, etc.

Also, the PubSub pattern is great because of its flexibility. You can build master/slave applications, device to device, etc.

### C library [image: GitHub version]

The C library is very simple to add on any new device as long as you have a decent UART library on it.

You just have to instanciate a data structure called `TM_transport` (defined by `Telemetry`), and assign the 4 function pointers `read` `readable` `write` `writeable`.

```
// your device's uart library function signatures (usually you already have them)
int32_t read(void * buf, uint32_t sizeToRead);
int32_t readable();
int32_t write(void * buf, uint32_t sizeToWrite);
int32_t writeable();
```

To use Telemetry, you just have to add the following code

```
// At the beginning of main function, this is the ONLY code you have to add to support a new device with telemetry
TM_transport transport;
transport.read = read;
transport.write = write;
transport.readable = readable;
transport.writeable = writeable;

// Init telemetry with the transport structure
init_telemetry(&transport);  

// and you're good to start publishing
publish_i32("foobar",...
```

### Python library [image: PyPI version]

On the desktop side, there is the `pytelemetry` module that implements the protocol.

If you know python, the following code connects to a serial port, publishes once on topic `foo`, prints all received topics during 3 seconds then terminates.

```
import runner
import pytelemetry.pytelemetry as tm
import pytelemetry.transports.serialtransport as transports
import time

transport = transports.SerialTransport()
telemetry = tm.pytelemetry(transport)
app = runner.Runner(transport,telemetry)

def printer(topic, data):
    print(topic," : ", data)

options = dict()
options['port'] = "COM20"
options['baudrate'] = 9600

app.connect(options)

telemetry.subscribe(None, printer)
telemetry.publish('bar',1354,'int32')
time.sleep(3)

app.terminate()
```

If you don't know python, you can use the command line interface

### Pytelemetry CLI [image: PyPI version]

The command line can be started with

```
pytlm
```

Then you can `connect`, `ls`(list) received topics, `print` data received on a topic, `pub`(publish) on a topic, or open a `plot` on a topic to display received data in real-time

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

My only suggestion is if you need noise-resistant you might want to use full-duplex RS-422/485.  You can use an IC similar to [this](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=ADM3488ARZ-ND) on the AVR side, then an RS-232->RS-422 converter on the PC side like [the 485PTBR here](http://www.bb-elec.com/product_family.asp?FamilyId=17&TrailType=Sub&Trail=11).  If you can find or make a shielded cable (two twisted shielded pairs) then you'll have even more protection. And all of this is invisible to the micro and PC - no software changes.

Whatever you do make sure that you are using a full-duplex system and make sure the read/write enable lines are asserted on the IC.

Answer (score 1):

You do not specify exactly how the microcontroller behaves, but will everything transmitted from the micro be a direct response to a command from the PC? If do then it seems like you can use a master/slave protocol of some kind (this will typically be the simplest solution). If both sides can initiate communication, you need a more general data link layer protocol. [HDLC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Level_Data_Link_Control) is a classic protocol for this. Although the full protocol probably is a overkill for your needs, you could for instance at least use the same frame format. You might also have a look at [PPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol) to see if there are something useful parts.

Comment: >> will everything transmitted from the micro be a direct response to a command from the PC?
A have not decided yet. I think yes, if it is simpler. A PC must know, when data is ready. It can continuously send command to micro, to ask if it ready to send. But maybe it will be better if a micro send signal to a PC, when data is ready.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this question can be completely stupid but has anyone considered use of one of [X/Y/Z MODEM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMODEM) protocols?

The main benefit of using one of above protocols is great availability of ready-to-use implementations in various programming environments.

Answer (score 0):

SLIP and UDP. Seriously.

All PC's and similar devices speak it.

There is a good book and examples from  [TCP Lean](http://www.iosoft.co.uk/tcplean.php)

Jeremy Bentham has sneakily got a PIC doing working TCP/IP. An AVR is as good as a PIC right ?

I'd recommend UDP instead, it's pretty darn easy.

Comment: UDP isn't reliable at all.

Comment: If we were talking about embedded computers (aka RPi, Odroids,...), I would have nodded. We are here talking about a micro-controller talking to one (and only one) PC. TCP and UDP (Header 16 bytes) are using IP (Header 16 bytes) which is using MAC (Header 14 bytes) which is using Ethernet (Framing 8 bytes + CRC 4 bytes). 

Putting this onto a µC is huge: to send a single byte, it will cost 58 bytes of overhead.