# Simple serial point-to-point communication protocol ---- sample code

Tags: serial-port

I had read this:
[Simple serial point-to-point communication protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815758/simple-serial-point-to-point-communication-protocol)

and I'm doing the same thing, and I don't want to reinvent wheel...

are there any API or sample code?

PS:
code in C/C++, python...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer ,
but go to [Jeremy Bentham's TCP/IP Lean site](http://www.iosoft.co.uk/tcplean.php)

You can easily get it to speak normal IP protocols.

Comment: Second this. Most of the API and libraries wrappers of varying thickness around Good old berkley sockets anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could in a couple of days implement something like the [Ash](http://www.ember.com/pdf/120-3010-000_UART-GatewayProtocolReference.pdf) specification by Ember.  It does address most of the issues pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

APIs, implemented by software, are product-specific and/or O/S-specific.

On an embedded system (which is the kind of system where serial comms is most prevalent) you'd use (perhaps buy) a library.

Answer (score 0):

Microcontroller Interconnect Network (MIN) code, written in 8-bit microcontroller embedded C and (for a PC etc.) also in Python:

https://github.com/min-protocol/min

Includes a "hello world" test program for an Arduino + PC described here:

https://kentindell.wordpress.com/2015/02/18/micrcontroller-interconnect-network-min-version-1-0/