# suggested protocol for android-arduino communication

Tags: android, arduino, adk

Using the Android Open Accessory standard, I have an android powered device talking back and forth with an arduino mega ADK microcontroller hooked up via USB. I would like to know what the best communication protocol is at the data link layer level.

From the android & arduino sides, it is simple file based IO e.g. write(buffer[], buffer_length), read(buffer[], buffer_length).

Doing some research, I came across this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815758/simple-serial-point-to-point-communication-protocol) entitled "simple serial point-to-point communication protocol" that recommends using the HDLC protocol. Would that be a good protocol to run with or is there something better?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It might be completely overkill to you, but I have successfully used [MQTT](http://mqtt.org/) to communicate [from an Arduino](http://knolleary.net/arduino-client-for-mqtt/) (over ethernet) to an [ActiveMQ broker](http://activemq.apache.org/mqtt.html) (this is likely where the overkill would happen in your case).

I will try to dig out some source code later today.

**Edit**: I found this [resource on Android/MQTT](http://mqtt.org/wiki/doku.php/mqtt_on_the_android_platform), which may be handy to you.

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks Ander. I'm not sure if MQTT is the right fit for me as it is geared high latency networks for multiple devices. QoS isn't really that big a deal to me and a pub/sub based protocol might be too much for point-to-point communication. I appreciate your input though. Cool work too btw!

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of ways by which you can make an Android and Arduino talk to each other. [Check out this presentation](http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/building-robots-using-arduino-and-android-at-droidcon) for some suggested ways.

If you could give your specific requirements, then I can suggested you the best protocol.

Comment: Thanks Sudar. Your presentation talks about communication at the physical layer. I'm interested in a protocol below that now that I have them already connected via USB.

Answer (score 1):

Detailed guide to using MQTT on Aurduino http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/redp4929.html

MQTT client for Aurdino http://knolleary.net/arduino-client-for-mqtt/

And there is tons of info re MQTT on Android here http://mqtt.org/wiki/mqtt_on_the_android_platform