# How wrap protobuf message for serial link

Tags: c#, .net, c, protocol-buffers

I have a protobuf communication between a embedded system and a PC application.
Communication is OK (serialize/deserialize).
But for more security i want add a frame management (wrap my protobuf message into a frame.)

embedded : nanopb ( lib protobuf)
pc: C# protobuf-net

The HDLC protocol can be the good way ?

ps: sorry for my english.

**Update:**

Sorry "security" was a bad word, i mean "robust".
The protobuf librairies are just here for information (context).

My project is in 3 steps

1) Basic protobuf communication over serial link ( serialize/deserilize) : status Finish

2) Manage communication to be sure all data are received before deserialize :status  in progress ( need your help)

I can receive datas in X part, when i read the port all datas are not received. (big message)

2.1) Use the timeout of receive data (serial port).(I think is not the good option)

2.2) Use a protocol for wrap the protobuf message into a "frame".
        And when i received data i can know if the frame is complete before try deserialize

```
    What is the best protocol ?(HDLC ?)
```

3) Encrypt/Decrypt protobuf message with AES : next step.

Comment: You haven't provided nearly enough information.  I'm not sure why you thought telling us the protobuf library you are using was more important than say, the communication interface. Anyway, here's an answer that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815758/simple-serial-point-to-point-communication-protocol

Comment: If you want to secure the communication, why don't you simply encrypt the serialized data?  In fact, if you want to secure your data, you have to encrypt it.  I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Yes, HDLC should be a fine choice.