# Does chrome.serial API ensure data integrity?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, google-chrome-app, hid, uart, data-integrity

I'm trying to understand whether its redundant for me to include some kind of CRC or checksum in my communication protocol.  Does the `chrome.serial` and other chrome hardware communication API's in general if anyone can speak to them (e.g. `chrome.hid`, `chrome.bluetoothLowEnergy`, ...)

Comment: You might need a few more relevant tags here to attract authoritative answers.

Comment: Any suggestions?  I couldn't find a tag for `chrome.serial`.

Comment: I mean, you might want generic tags for serial/usb/bluetooth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serial communications is simply a way of transmitting bits and its major reason for existence is that it's one bit at a time -- and can therefore work over just a single communications link, such as a simple telephone line. There's no built-in CRC or checksum or anything.

There are many systems that live on top of serial comms that attempt to deal with the fact that communications often takes place in a noisy environment. Back in the day of modems over telephone lines, you might have to deal with the fact that someone else in the house might pick up another extension on the phone line and inject a bunch of noise into your download. Thus, protocols like XMODEM were invented, wrappering serial comms in a more robust framework. (Then, when XMODEM proved unreliable, we went to YMODEM and ZMODEM.)

Depending on what you're talking to (for example, a device like an Arduino connnected to a USB serial port over a wire that's 25 cm long) you might find that putting the work into checksumming the data isn't worth the trouble, because the likelihood of interference is so low and the consequences are trivial. On the other hand, if you're talking to a controller for a laser weapon, you might want to make sure the command you send is the command that's received.

I don't know anything about the other systems you mention, but I'm old enough to have spent a lot of time doing serial comms back in the '80s (and now doing it again for devices using chrome.serial, go figure).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Chrome's serial API to communicate with Arduino devices, and I have yet to experience random corruption in the middle of an exchange (my exchanges are short bursts, 50-500 bytes max). However, I do see garbage bytes blast out if a connection is flaky or a cable is "rudely" disconnected (like a few minutes ago when I tripped over the FTDI cable).

In my project, a mis-processed command wont break anything, and I can get by with a master-slave protocol. Because of this, I designed a pretty slim solution: The Arduino slave listens for an "attention byte" (!) followed by a command byte, after which it reads a fixed number of data bytes depending on the command. Since the Arduino discards until it hears an attention byte and a valid  command, the breaking-errors usually occur when a connection is cut while a slave is "awaiting x data bytes". To account for this, the first thing the master does on connect is to blindly blast out enough AT bytes to push the Arduino through "awaiting data" even in the worst-case-scenario. Crude, yet sufficient.

I realize my solution is pretty lo-fi, so I did a bit of surfing around and I found this post to be pretty comprehensive: [Simple serial point-to-point communication protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815758/simple-serial-point-to-point-communication-protocol?lq=1)

Also, if you need a strategy for error-**correction** over error-detection/re-transmission (or over my strategy, which I guess is "error-brute-forcing"), you may want to check out the link to a technique called "Hamming," near the bottom of that thread - That one looked promising!

Good luck!

-Matt