# How do you design a serial command protocol for an embedded system?

Tags: embedded, serial-port

I have an embedded system I'm communicating with over serial. The command structure right now is designed to be operated interactively: it displays a prompt, accepts a few commands, and displays results in a human-readable form.

I'm thinking about changing this to a more machine-usable format, so I can talk to it through a MATLAB GUI without too much trouble (right now it's hiccuping on the interactive prompts and varying message lengths, etc.).

So is there a document or standard somewhere that describes how to design a good serial command protocol for your embedded system?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815758 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815029

Comment: What is this embedded system, and how do you intend to use the serial interface?

Comment: This is an active sensor system; it generates a signal and waits for a response. The serial interface is mainly for control (and debugging as well): set signal parameters, operate the system; return data.

Answer (score 56):

I have some preferences (and pet peeves) from writing software to control media and display devices using RS232.  Depending on your hardware, some of these may not apply:

- I think it's a good idea to make your protocol more friendly for automation.  If you need an interactive interface (command line or other), build it separately and have it use the automation protocol.  I wouldn't worry too much about making it human readable, but it's up to you.
- Always return a response, even (especially) if you get an invalid command.  Something simple like $06 for ACK and $15 for NAK.  Or spell it out if you want it to be slightly more human readable.
- If you can set any value, make sure there's some way to query that same value.  If you have a lot of values, it could take a while to query them all.  Consider having one or just a few meta-queries that return several values at once.
- If you have information that can't be set, but is important (model no, serial no, version, copyright, etc), make sure these can be queried instead of just displaying them once on startup or reset.
- Never respond with an error for a valid command.  You'd think this one would be obvious...
- Speaking of obvious, document the serial settings your hardware supports.  Especially if it's going to be used by anyone other than you and you don't want them to spend the first 30 minutes trying to figure out if they can't talk to the device because of the serial port, the connections, the cable or their software.  Not that I'm bitter...
- Use absolute commands instead of toggle values.  For example, have separate commands for Power On and Power Off instead of sending the same command and having the power toggle on and off.
- Responses should include information on the command they are responding to.  This way any program doesn't need to remember the last thing it asked for in order to deal with the response (see extra credit option below).
- If your device supports a standby mode (off, but not really off), make sure queries still work while you're in this state.

Depending on how paranoid you are about data completeness:

- Wrap your message in an envelope.  The header could include a starting character, the lengeth of the message and a closing character.  Just in case you get partial or malformed messages.  Maybe $02 for the start and $03 for the end.
- If you're really paranoid about message integrity, include a checksum.  They can be a bit of a pain, though.

For extra credit:

- If your hardware settings can be changed manually, maybe send this change out the serial port as if the user had queried it.  For example, you might not want the user to be able to change the input source for a public display monitor.

I hope this helps.

**Update:**

I forgot something important.  Before you either use this seriously and especially before you give it out to someone else, try it out on something trivial to make sure it works the way you expect it to and (more importantly) to make sure you haven't left anything out.  It will take more time and effort to fix things if you find a problem in the middle of a bigger project.

This is a good rule of thumb whether you're designing a command protocol, a web service, a database schema or a class, etc.

Comment: I agree with all of this post.  Although I would argue a little stronger for human readable format(Ascii)  1. easier to trouble shoot 2. no need for special test tools, just use hyper term or tera term
3. easier to describe how to use to a less sophisticated customer. 

I typically do wrap the command with Start Of Packet and End Of Packet Characters, and a length after the Start of Packet.  You could get away with the EOP being the '/n' return character if you want make use of complete line parsing.

Comment: If this is a requirement, then I don't have any objection to that.  Wrap your message in something like square brackets, make the length and any other values human readable as well (don't mix and match).  My aversion to this came from a couple of VERY long winded (and inconsistent) protocols.

Comment: If you use an envelope, please be sure to keep the envelope separate from the thing it wraps. I've got a protocol write now where they don't, and it's a big pain in the ass to parse.

Comment: @Michael Kohne, or you will have escape the character that may show up in your data. But I agree this can be a pain; so avoid using character that may show up in your data is a fist choice.

Comment: I agree with all of it except the framing, I think that is required not optional.  A start pattern, a length and a checksum on every packet, period.  A sequence number is optional depending on what you are doing it is required, and an ending pattern is optional.

Comment: @dwelch: If you prefer to make the protocol human readable at least partly so you can test with a terminal app, checksums make this more awkward.  Not an argument against checksums, just an observation.

Comment: @Bruce: Thanks for the informative comment, you've helped me immensely to frame the issue. So the only thing that remains to be asked is: is it best to design my own protocol, or use some predefined or standard one? Other answered have mentioned Modbus and Firmata, and I've read up on SCPI; do you have any experience with these?

Comment: @joeljkp - I haven't used these standards.  Most of my experience comes from working with existing protocols from different vendors, and I helped write the document that Popai adopted as one of their protocol standards.  This was largely focusing on finding (or forcing) enough common ground tome up with a sane abstraction for multiple devices.  My experience might not apply directly to your situation, so take this with a grain of salt;  Unless I had a good reason to use a predefined standard, I would design my own protocol.

Comment: I would also add that commands should also have a unique identifier and responses should include that identifier.  That way your conversation is <id><cmd> followed by <id><ACK> or <id><NAK>.

Comment: @plinth: Agreed.  That's what I meant by "Responses should include information on the command they are responding to."  In addition to making things easier to track if responses are received out of order for any reason, I've found this it makes it easier to test client code without having the physical device available.

Comment: Always, always, always include a checksum (or better yet, a good CRC). Never assume data integrity, especially when it's not all that hard to check for it with a high degree of confidence.

Answer (score 15):

[Here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/08/12/framing-in-serial-communications/) is a great article by Eli Benderski on serial protocol framing. Whatever the packet format you chose, be sure to use escape characters. It allows you to have such characters inside actual data and makes it really easy to re-synchronize in case of packet corruption.

Comment: The article suggests that "special" characters should be preceded by an escape character but sent verbatim.  That's common practice, but I really dislike it since it makes the sequence "escape start-flag" context-sensitive.

Comment: [COBS](http://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/113.php) is better than escaping characters.

Comment: Didn't know COBS. Nice.

Comment: The [MIN protocol](https://github.com/min-protocol/min) uses three 0xAA characters in a row to mark the beginning of a frame, and then byte-stuffing to ensure that three never happen in a row across the rest of the frame. This makes it easy for the receiver's state machine to reset whenever 0xAA 0xAA 0xAA is received and so stay in sync (0xAA is chosen because 10101010 in binary makes for a nice pulsetrain to do auto baud rate detection).

Answer (score 8):

Unless bandwidth or latency is a big issue, use ASCII where you can - it makes debugging much easier.

I'm fond of protocols that send a message then a clear 'message end' character (such as 'carriage return'). I don't generally find start of packet signals to be that helpful (what else is on that wire?) Using CR for message end also makes it easier to test via terminal program.

Update: Bruce pointed out (in the comments) that a start of packet character lets you find the packets slightly quicker in the case of corruption. Without the start of packet character, it would take until the end of the next packet before you knew where you were and at that point you'd be throwing out 2 packets instead of one.

Comment: A start of envelope character is useful if you consistently get dropped characters or partial packets.  We've found RS232 can be unreliable.  Even more so when you are dealing with serial port extenders or serial over TCPIP.

Comment: Start of Packet can also be useful if you have an asynchornous command and response system, where you might get multiple commands and you need to find the begining of the next command in the stream.  Or the higher level code can receive buffer with more than one command.

Comment: @Bruce McGee - OK, I'll buy that - if you lost the previous end of packet, then the presence of a start of packet lets you throw out the bad one without losing the following 'good' one, I guess.

Comment: @simon - on a real serial system (which this question is about) you only have one packet on the wire at a time. As Bruce said, SOP might be good for dealing with lost packets, but it doesn't matter for dealing with async - that depends on being able to match up commands and responses based on something (usually envelope data). SOP doesn't enter into it.

Comment: @Michael Kohne I'm thinking some thing like SLIP, PPP, ZMODEM, where you might send multiple packets before you ACK.

Comment: Another point.  Just because you are dealing with serial devices doesn't mean you can assume one device per port.  Some devices support daisy chaining, so you could have multiple devices on one serial port.  Or (as in my case), you could have a single server accepting several network connections from PCs, each talking directly to one or more serial devices.  Another thing I notices was vendors offering dual external interfaces, like serial and TCPIP.

Comment: @Bruce - agreed, multi-drop serial is something I've dealt with before. But, a serial port (or a TCP socket for that matter) can only have one packet on it at a time, which is all I was concerned about. Keeping different devices straight is something I'd want in the envelope, but there's many ways to skin that cat.

Comment: @simon - yes, you might well have more than one packet before you ACK. But you'll still only have one packet on the wire at a time, and start-of-packet/end-of-packet characters are really just to find packets, not for anything else.

Comment: Or, unless embedded system code size and complexity is an issue. I would argue in favour of keeping the embedded code as simple as possible, and move as much of the complexity into PC software as possible. So if you need a nice human interface, provide it via PC software.

Answer (score 7):

I like Bruce McGee's answers.  Having worked with similar interfaces I can offer several other pointers:

- When returning numeric types in a data packet, please please PLEASE try to make everything the same format.  Don't have *single* for some numbers and *double* for others.  And don't make it arbitrary!
- Provide examples for data packets in your ICD.  It's terribly frustrating to have to guess at byte order or even bit order (is MSByte first, or last?  What is first and last?).  Provide a diagram that shows packets vs. time (ie, 0x02 is sent earliest, then the address byte, then the message id, etc).
- Don't switch around between data formats if at all possible.  I've worked in systems that use 'ASCII-encoded numbers' for some messages where you have to strip the leading '3' off of the bytes, then pull them together to make the real number.  (Usually ASCII-encoding is used when you have a byte sequence you have to avoid, like 0x02, 0x04, etc.  Encoded the numbers would be 0x30, 0x32, 0x30, 0x34.  Use a length field if possible to avoid this, or at least do it all the time!)
- Definitely definitely definitely document the baud rate, parity, etc.  If you're using RS-485 document the bus mode (2-wire? 4-wire?) or whatever settings will appear on the machine that you intend this to be used on.  Give screenshots if you have to.

This interface will probably be very useful for debug.  I've worked with some systems that had debug features such as:

- A system where the programmer made a list of 'logged parameters' (internal variables).  You would tell the system which ones you wanted reported (up to 8) and then when you queried the system for the logged parameters it would return them in one data packet.  I liked this, but depending on the complexity of the system you may or may not be able to specify them at run-time (or you could do something simple and send the system a mask that would select the ones you want returned).
- Data packets that 'break' behavior
  and allow parts of the system to be
  tested independently (ie, on a D/A put out this voltage, on a DIO port stim this byte, etc)

Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

If you must have your own protocol,

**Please please please use packet framing.**

SLIP Framing only a few lines of code.  Specified in (RFC 1055)

So now all packets can always look like this

```
 <slip packet start>
 message
 message crc
 <slip packet start>
```

Don't send a message length. It can get corrupted and then the receiver message parsers get confused.

If your receiver has a small receiver buffer and it overflows, you just keep reading till the packet boundary.  No harm done.

Plenty of simple 2 byte CRC's; the Xmodem one is easy. You can just xor all the bytes in the packet it you must.

If you wanted to be a really nice person, use PPP, DDNS and HTTP-REST for your actual commands. 
Lovely book on doing this on 16 series PIC processor in C by Jeremy Bentham, TCP/IP Lean.

Then you can use a web browser to talk to it, or something like libcurl from C code.
As almost every programming language has libraries to do http, everyone can talk to your device.

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of good suggestions and ideas here and notice that there are different ways to tackle it for different purposes.  Having used many serial protocols both good and bad as well having made several of my own (both good and bad...) here are a few of my suggestions and comments.

- Keep it simple.  I have found the
  greatest success with simple header
  based command-response "packets".
- Don't worry about human readable ASCII.  It is only useful for the few hours you actually debug your protocol.  After that it is restrictive to always encode data as ASCII and very inefficient if you  transfer a lot of data.
- Use error checking.  I prefer a 16   bit CRC as it provides orders of   magnitude of protection over a   checksum and is still simple and   efficient over heavier algorithms   like MD5 or SHA1.
- Use the same packet format for the   commands as the responses.
- Use 8 bit data with no parity. Serial parity bit doesn't add anyprotection if you already use a CRCor other data integrity check and isa poor error check at best.
- So in the simplest form the packet   header is the Command or Response,   size of the packet, zero or more dataand the error checking code (CRC).

Comment: Even though I lean away from human readable protocols, they can have advantages beyond debugging when it's first created.  It can be useful for any third parties writing software to communicate with the device.

Answer (score 3):

FTP is an example of a protocol that works reasonably well both interactively and with automation.  One key is that responses start with a code that indicates whether an automated client should pay attnetion or not. Similarly for POP3.

One nice thing about those protocols is that when your developing/debugging you can reasonbly drive the communication from a regular terminal or script the communication using regular shell scripts/batch files/whatever.

However, one thing they don't do is provide reliability - that's provided by a lower layer of the comm stack.  It's something that should be considered in most embedded communication pahs.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at Modbus (http://www.modbus.org/)?  It's a fairly simple protocol which includes a checksum on each message.  It also sends a response to every command, even those which don't need a "return value", so you know if your command got received correctly.  The only choice you would have after choosing Modbus would be the register addresses to store your data at, and the format of any user defined functions (which the MODBUS protocol allows).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Firmata](http://firmata.org/wiki/Protocol) as an example protocol.

Comment: Have any experience with SCPI?

Comment: The SCIP specification is here: ivifoundation.org/docs/SCPI-99.PDF