# Serial Comms programming structure in c# / net /

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I'm an embedded programmer trying to do  a little bit of coding for a communications app and need a quick start guide on the best  / easiest way to do something.

I'm successfully sending serial data packets but need to impliment some form of send/ response protocol to avoid overflow on the target system and to ensure that the packet was received ok.

Right now - I have all the transmit code under a button click and it sends the whole lot without any control.
What's the best way to structure this code , i.e sending some packets - waiting for response .. sending more .. etc etc until it's all done, then carrying on with the main program.
I've not used threads or callbacks or suchlike in  this environment before but will learn - I just need a pointer to the most straigtforward ways to do it.

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 1):

The .NET serialport uses buffers, learn to work with them.

Sending packets that are (far) smaller than the Send-buffer can be done w/o threading.

Receiving can be done by the DataReceived event but beware that that is called from another thread. You might as well start your own thread and use blocking reads from there.

The best approach depends on what your 'packets' and protocol look like.

Answer (score 1):

I think to have a long experience about serial comm, both MCU and PC-based.
I strongly UNSUGGEST the single-thread based solution, although it is very straigthful for light-speed testing, but absolutely out for final releases.
Surely you may choose among several patterns, but they are mostly shaped around a dedicated thread for the comm process and a finite-state-machine to parse the protocol (during receiveing).
The prevoius answers give you an idea to how build a simple program, but it might depends on the protocol specification, target device, scope of the application, etc.

Answer (score 0):

there are of course different ways.

I will describe a thread based and an async operation based way:

- If you don't use threads, your app will block as long as the operation is performing. This is not what a user is expecting today. Since you are talking about a series of sending and receiveing commands, I would recommend starting the protocol as a thread and then waiting for it to finish. You might also place an Abort button if neccesary. Set the ReadTimeout values and at every receive be ready to catch the exception! An introducing into creating such a work thread is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4%28VS.80%29.aspx)
- If you want to, use Async Send/Receive functions instead of a thread (e.g. [NetworkStream.BeginRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.beginread%28VS.80%29.aspx) etc.). But this is more difficult because you have to manage state between the calls: I recommend using a Finite State Machine then. In fact you create an enumeration (i.e. ProtocolState) and change the state whenever an operation has completed. You can then simply create a function that performs the next step of the protocol with a simple switch/case statement. Since you are working with a remote entity (in your case the serial target system), you always have to consider the device is not working or stops working during the protocol. Do this by starting a timeout timer (e.g. set to 2000ms) and start it after sending each command (assuming each command will get a reply in your protocol). Stop it if the command was received successfully or on timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You could also implement low-level handshaking on the serial port; set the serial port's Handshake property to rts/cts or xon/xoff.

Otherwise (or in addition), use a background worker thread. For simple threads, I like a Monitor.Wait/Pulse mechanism for managing the thread.

I have some code that does read-only serial communications in a thread; email me and I'll be happy to send it to you.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure from your question if you were designing both the PC and embedded sides of the communication link, if you are you might find [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445387/how-do-you-design-a-serial-command-protocol-for-an-embedded-system) interesting.