# Literature on how to implement ASCII command protocol for uC using sequence numbers and XOR error correction?

Tags: linux, serial-port, protocols, protocol-buffers, rs485

i come accross a half duplex ASCII protocol that uses following message format again and again:
[STX][dev.addr.][sequence number][message/commands...][ETX][checksum]

not only in industrial rs485 devices, but also in this consumer device:
www.kaleidescape.com/go/control-protocol

so if this protocol is so widely adopted, why can't i find informations about it.. what is it called? how does one implement such a protocol...

i wanna use this kind of protocol with my own uC projects...

i definitely like it's conceptual simplicity, compared to other protocols..

i like this Sequence Number/Repeat Flag thing...

The sequence number is a single byte that conveys both a sequence number (legal values: 0 to 7) and a bit-flag indicating that the command block is being repeated due to a communications breakdown. The sequence number is used as an identity stamp for each command block

this question is the only valuable information i could find...
[How do you design a serial command protocol for an embedded system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445387/how-do-you-design-a-serial-command-protocol-for-an-embedded-system)

is there a book about the design and implemention of ASCII protocols for uC use?